# How to compare two fields in the same document in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 7.2.0,
I have documents in an index with three fields - `id, field1, field2`
I want to query and return those documents whose `field1 > 20` AND `field1 > field2`

**Following is the data that the index has -**
[image]

**Following is the query that I'm trying -**

```
GET /test/_search
 {
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                              "range" : {
                      "field1" : {
                          "gte" : 20
                      }
                  }
                            },
                              {
                                "script": {
                  "source": "doc['field1'].value > doc['field2'].value",
                "params": {
                }
              }}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Following is the error -**

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[script] query does not support [source]",
        "line": 18,
        "col": 29
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[script] query does not support [source]",
    "line": 18,
    "col": 29
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct! You just need to wrap the `script` inside another `script`. The first is to denote a `script` query, the second is to actually define the script:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "constant_score": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "field1": {
                      "gte": 20
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "script": {
                    "script": {
                      "source": "doc['field1'].value > doc['field2'].value",
                      "params": {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome, worked and thanks for the explanation, I'll mark in 8mins, you're too quick for Stack :D